# Get only specific data on a product query in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to get all products from WooCommerce in an array, which I will use later for syncing with an external database.

In the following code, I am using `wc_get_products()` function that returns for each product a very huge amount of data *(that I don't need mostly)*:

```php
$args = array(
'status' => 'publish',
'limit' => -1,
);
$wooExistingProducts = wc_get_products($args);
```

Instead what I can do to only get the product Id, the product name and the product price?

For each product, I would like to have something like:

```
[
{
id: 315892135,
name: Food for Hamster
price: 5$
}
{
id: 129414,
name: ....
price:...
}
....
]
```

I've tried to use a `WP_Query` instead, but did not provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the only available filter for [wc_get_products()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) is `'return' => 'ids'` to get only product IDS when using a [`WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query).

**The solution** is to use a **direct SQL Query** with WordPress [WPDB](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class as  it's the **lighter** and **most effective** way to get the data as you want in a product query.

In the following query, we are obliged to exclude variable products as they have multiple prices *(one for each variation)*:

```
global $wpdb;

$products_query = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT  p.ID AS id,
            p.post_title AS name,
            Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_price' AND  p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END) AS price
    FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm
                ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE   p.post_type = 'product'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
            AND p.post_parent != 0
    GROUP BY p.ID
    ORDER BY p.ID ASC;
" );

// Testing raw output
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $products_query ); echo '</pre>';
```

---

**INCLUDING PRODUCT VARIATIONS** *(option)*:

If you want to include the product variations of a variable product, you should replace this line:

```
WHERE   p.post_type = 'product'
```

by:

```
WHERE   p.post_type IN ('product','product_varation')
```

---

> I don't recommend you to use `wc_get_products()` or `get_posts()` *(WP_Query)* in your case:
>
> - as you will get also variable products *(that have multiple prices depending on its variations)*
> - as it's much more heavier *(even if you query only `'ids'` field, to get only product Ids)*, because you will have to set the data for each product, making multiple database queries.